# MongoDB: How to handle two users uploading the same username or password at the same time

Tags: database, mongodb, passwords

This situation might not happen much, but I would rather be safe than sorry. I'm currently trying to make a sign in/sign up system with flutter MongoDB using API call to my database. On the signup screen, I am making checks to see if the data placed into the password and username text fields already exists within the database. In other words, if an account with those credentials already exists then I ask the user to try again, but if there isn't one then I allow for the user to go to the EULA and submit page.

The problem here is that I feel like that two  or more users can do the same check at the same time, and will get the same result because, while their information might match, there isn't an instance of an account with those credentials uploaded to the database for the system to tell them to stop before they go to the submit page. And if they submit the data they wrote on their phones to the database at the same time, a situation is made where we have multiple instances of the same kind of account existing in the database.

I know that keys exist and can help in making each account unique from each other, but, in this situation, I am not sure on how to handle or prevent the concurrent uploading of similar or identical data from local devices to the same server. Are calls to my server and MongoDB asynchornous? Is this something that I need to worry about at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: If you use a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) on the `username` field, then it will raise an error on attempting to create a duplicate, and you can forward this to the user's sign up page and let them change their name.

---

### The long answer:

This is more of a UX problem than a DB problem.
If I understand correctly, the user enters a username & password, then reads the EULA before the account is created.

I would disagree with this - you should make the account once they submit their name, and update it with a Boolean for `eulaAccepted` so that if this process fails (eg. bad connection) they can come back and accept it later.

You should do two sets of unique username validation:

1. When they type in the name, you can check for them and let them know the name is available. This still means someone else could take it before they hit save.
2. Once they hit save. Put a unique index on the username field. Then if a user tries saving a duplicate (even if submitted simultaneously, they will be processed sequentially) then it will raise an error. You can forward this onto the user, prompting them to try a different name.

Answering your other questions:

> Are calls to my server and MongoDB asynchronous?

Yes, as they go over the network they are naturally asynchronous. But the saves inside the Database itself are sequential and atomic. MongoDB is [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant. have a read through what it means, and [what changed in version 4](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-multi-document-acid-transactions-general-availability)

> Is this something that I need to worry about at all?

Yes, it's good to keep an eye on this sort problems. If you don't consider it now, you will have a nasty bug on your hand later.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented exactly what you said and it works so well. I applied the unique ID to both the username and password fields of my database, which only lowered the possibility of dupilicates. At least I know what to do now when working with databases in the future.